# What song is playing in Naruto: Shippuden season 6 episode 117 at 2:49?

Tags: music-identification, naruto

There is a scene where Jugo and Kimimaro meet. Jugo wants to fight him first and he runs in Kimimaro's direction, but then he realizes that it is actually Kimimaro. Then a song plays.

What is that song called?

Comment: Is there a reason to assume it wasn't just written for the show?

Comment: I did not know there was such a thing as a music-identification tag.